# Not able to display background

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have downloaded a template to work on using asp.net c# and the background is not displaying on running the web form using a user control although it is displaying in the design section[design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0F5T.png)
[Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csEMq.png)

Comment: The problem is most likely in file `abcd.aspx`, line `1234`. If not please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask can be useful also.